# Calling a docker container from jenkins (permissions denied on socket)

Tags: macos, docker, jenkins, docker-for-mac

I'm trying to run a Docker image from a Jenkins pipeline but I am getting this common permission error:

```
[devops-lab] Running shell script
+ docker run -d --mount source=devops-lab,target=/root/data pmaugeri/alpine-akamai-cli
docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.37/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I observed that this socket is owned by *daemon* group:

```
$ ls -la /var/run/docker.sock
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  daemon  61 May 24 15:50 /var/run/docker.sock -> /Users/pmaugeri/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/s60
```

Note that there is no *docker* group on my system.

So I did try to add the *jenkins* user in the *daemon* group but it didn't solve this issue.

Here is the definition of my pipeline:

```
node {
    sh 'env > env.txt' 
    for (String i : readFile('env.txt').split("\r?\n")) {
        println i
    }
    sh 'whoami' 
    docker.image('pmaugeri/alpine-akamai-cli').withRun('--mount source=devops-lab,target=/root/data') {    
    }
}
```

and here is the jenkins console output:

```
...
[devops-lab] Running shell script
+ whoami
jenkins
[Pipeline] sh
[devops-lab] Running shell script
+ docker run -d --mount source=devops-lab,target=/root/data pmaugeri/alpine-akamai-cli
docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.37/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Can you please help me to make this simple pipeline to work?

Thanks in advance

Pascal

Here is my system configuration:

- MacOS: macOS Sierra v10.12.6
- Jenkins version: 2.122
- Docker version: 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40

Comment: The solution to all problems like this is 1. create docker group 2. add jenkins user to docker group 3. restart docker service.

Comment: Thanks for your response Matt.  It is still not clear to me how I can make Docker to run under the "docker" group. Do you happen to know some document that explains that?